# 2D obstacle collision

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

Hi I am trying to make 2d collision but I dont get it to work 
i am doing :

```
if (collider.posX + collider.sizeX >= obstacle.posX && obstacle.posX + obstacle.sizeX >= collider.posX && collider.posY + collider.sizeY >= obstacle.posY)
```

the obstacle cannot move on the y axis so this is why i only check for

```
collider.posY + 50 >= obstacle.posY
```

the collision works but they are only start when the obstacle is half in the collider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
if( obstacle.posX >= collider.posX && 
    obstacle.posX <= collider.posX + collider.sizeX &&
    obstacle.posY >= collider.posY && 
    obstacle.posY <= collider.posY + collider.sizeY
  )
```

This code should check if obstacle point intersects collider rectangle.
This is better solution because it detects overlapping between 2 rectangles:

```
if ( obstacle.posX <= collider.posX + collider.sizeX &&
     obstacle.posX + obstacle.sizeX >= collider.posX &&
     obstacle.posY <= collider.posY + collider.sizeY &&
     obstacle.posY + obstacle.sizeY >= collider.posY )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into logical errors, seen by the following code:

```
collider.posX + collider.sizeX >= obstacle.posX
```

Suppose the two colliding objects are circles with their positions being their center points. The first object is moving in the positive X direction while the second is static (stationary). You need to check if the first object's X position plus its radius (not diameter) touches the second object's X position minus its radius.

Example code:

```
collider.posX + (collider.sizeX / 2) >= obstacle.posX - (obstacle.sizeX / 2)
```

**Note:** The above inequality assumes that `collider.sizeX` represents the diameter of `collider`.

Presumably later on you'll also need to check if the first object is passed the second object. Since the above inequality only accounts for the first object having an increasing X position and its X position being less than the second object's X position.